# v-html of Vue doesn't support promise，etc，all of vue binding value doesn't support promise，is there a solution?

Tags: vue.js

[code in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNleR.png)
the formatter method, may include async method, and may be use async and await，when i use, page render uncorrectly。Is there a solution?

Comment: Yeah, don't use a framework in the first place. And **never** post images of code.

Comment: Please, don't post the code as images. It's unclear what you exactly mean. You know what is `formatter` and how it's related to promises, other users don't. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do not send code in images, as this is very inconvenient to answer. And please do not add links to external pages unless it is an official documentation.

Vue only binds variables which are defined in the data section.

So this should work:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            scope: {
                data: {row: []}
```

but this will not bind the row records:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            scope: {} // does not work with scope.data.row
```